# Kotlin object's as an injection point for spigot

Tags: kotlin, minecraft, bukkit

I've been using the Kotlin with the Bukkit framework and so far it has been great. I am having one major issue though. Bukkit requires that the main plugin class be a class, so that spigot can create an instance of it.

I am writing a library for Kotlin with the Bukkit framework since it was originally written in Java. The main problem I have is that nearly all methods require an instance of the JavaPlugin class, but I don't want to use dependency injection. Having an object, or static access to the JavaPlugin instance would solve this problem.

Is there any way that I can create some sort of wrapper or something of that nature to delegate the behavior of the class to an object?

Comment: What have you tried to do, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Well, I have tried making my plugin class an object, but this doesn't work because the bukkit framework has to instantiate it.

Comment: Showing a quick example is great for us to see what you're actually trying to achieve! If you could update your post with an example of what you want, we could help you better

Comment: For instance, what are you trying to do that requires it to be an object? Calling methods in a static way?

Comment: Well, I am writing a library for Kotlin with the Bukkit framework since it was originally written in Java. The main problem I have is that nearly all methods require an instance of the JavaPlugin class, but I don't want to use dependency injection. Having an object, or static access to the JavaPlugin instance would solve this problem.

Comment: See, that's a clear explanation and it's not in your question. Could you edit it to add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a singleton instance, as you cannot use object; Bukkit must construct your JavaPlugin, therefore you can't use a direct singleton. You can implement your own using something similar to this:

```
class Plugin : JavaPlugin() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: Plugin
        private set
    }

    override fun onEnable() {
        instance = this
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call this class somewhat as an object, as long as you put your methods in the companion object

```
Plugin.instance.doSomething()
```

or add methods to that companion object to do something with the instance, instead of getting the instance directly, then you could use the most similar Object syntax

```
Plugin.doSomethingWithInstance()
```

I don't believe there are other solutions to this yet, but this gets pretty close to what you want

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I knew about this feature but hadn't considered using it in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a way to do that with an object, however you can fake an object by using a global variable:

```
val Injection: InjectionClass
    get() = injectionInstance
private lateinit var injectionInstance: InjectionClass

class InjectionClass {
    init { injectionInstance = this }

    var someVar = 0
}
```

Then in another file you can use `Injection.someVar` just like if `Injection` was an object. The one downside of this is that IntelliJ IDEA's syntax highlighting shows `Injection` as purple italics as opposed to white, but other than that and having to use `InjectionClass` if you ever need to specify it as a type it should work perfectly

Comment: This way wouldn't be what OP wants, using it as an Object from the Plugin instance, you'd need to reference an instance as opposed to referencing the class itself

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't the same as the accepted answer, except with a little syntactic sugar on top. Objects are literally syntactic sugar for singletons, and this allows you to effectively use the same static-like syntax as an object.

Comment: I think that holding a top level instance this way seems to hide that the class is doing things statically. In a way that this doesn't seem that the classe is doing things, but the instance is doing

Comment: I think that with an Object, although it's just syntatic sugar, it looks more related to the class